# How is best practise using AMD and RequireJS, when namespacing an entire file

Tags: scope, requirejs, amd, procedural

I am new to AMD, and I've been wondering about how one can have a file like this, mixed functions and logic:

```
function abc() {
    ....
}

function def() {
    ....
}

function ghi() {
    ....
}

var something = { ... }

if (abc === something) {
    for(var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
       ...
    }
}

... And so it goes on for 1200 lines or so.
```

So not everything in this file is inside functions, there is also just logic being executed outside functions.

How can I include a file like this in another module, and make sure all these functions and what not are NOT in the global namespace/scoped in AMD style?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap entire file contents into a module definition:

```javascript
define(function () {
function abc() {
    // ....
}

function def() {
    // ....
}

function ghi() {
    // ....
}

var something = { /* ... */ }

if (abc === something) {
    for(var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
       // ...
    }
}

// ... And so it goes on for 1200 lines or so.
});
```

Then in the other module just require the thing from the above :) But none of those functions will be available to the module which needs the wrapped code. But that can also be sorted, just return them in the object literal at the end of the wrapped file